# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, variables, input

I have this code:

```
def delete():
    print("Welcome to the password delete system.")
    file = open("pypyth.txt", "w")
    output =  []
    linechoice = input("What password do you want to delete?:\n")
    if linechoice == "email":
        for line in file:
            if "Hotmail" != line.strip():
                output.append(line)
                print("Password " + linechoice + " deleted.")
                y_n = input = ("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")
                if y_n == "y":
                    file.close()
                    print("Change saved.")
                    input("Press enter to go back to menu")
                    main()
                else:
                    main()
    elif linechoice == "skype":
        for line in file:
            if "Skype" != line.strip():
                output.append(line)
                print("Password " + linechoice + " deleted.")
                y_n = input = ("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")
                if y_n == "y":
                    file.close()
                    print("Change saved.")
                    input("Press enter to go back to menu")
                    main()
                else:
                    main()
    else:
```

Why do I get an error like so?

```
    linechoice = input("What password do you want to delete?:\n")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You are assigning to `input` in the line `y_n = input = ("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")` and `y_n = input = ("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")`, overwriting the built-in function `input`.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a string to the variable `input` in

```
y_n = input = ("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")
```

`input` now has the value of `'Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n'`

However, you are also calling the built-in function `input` in

```
linechoice = input("What password do you want to delete?:\n")
```

Consider changing the name of your variable to avoid these conflicts.

Looking at the context of the program, you are probably expecting

```
y_n = input("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")
```

instead of

```
y_n = input = ("Do you want to save these changes?\ny/n\n")
```

Comment: Doesn't explain the error however. It should result in `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Comment: @Nabla no it wouldn't, because the assignment happens *after* the reference - but an assignment anywhere in a function makes the name local throughout that function, hence the NameError.

Comment: Great job of coding gumshoery!

Comment: You're not explaining the real reason behind the `UnboundLocalError` at all, which is that the name `input` becomes a local variable of a function when it is assigned a value anywhere in the function, and that a local variable cannot be read until it is assigned a value.

Answer (score -1):

If you got this error, due to calling ***input()***:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment

than you should check whether your **runtime python interpreter is 3.x**, if you were assuming it is 2.x.

This Error happened to me while executing on python 3.6:

```
if hasattr(__builtins__, 'raw_input'): 
    input = raw_input
input()
```

So I got rid of this, and instead used:

```
from builtins import input
```