# Defining Python function with user input

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to create a small piece of code that uses pythagoras' theorem to calculate the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle and the angle opposite the height. To do this, the user has to enter the length and width of the triangle. I want to define a function so that the whole thing can be called as part of a larger program. Here's the code:

```
def ex1() :
    from math import sqrt, atan, degrees
    print("""Hello, this is a program that will calculate the length of the
    hypotenuse of a triangle given the width and height of the triangle.
    It will also calculate the angle opposite the height and adjacent to the width.
    """)

    myWidth = float(input("Please input the width of the triangle: "))
    myHeight = float(input("Please input the height of the triangle: "))
    hyp = sqrt(((myWidth**2) + (myHeight**2)))
    angle = degrees(atan(myHeight/myWidth))
    print("\nThe length of the hypotenuse is " + "%.1f" % hyp + " units")
    print("\nThe size of the angle opposite the height and \nadjacent to the width is " + "%.1f" % angle + " degrees to 1 decimal place")
    input = input("Press enter to end the program\n")
```

Can anyone explain to me that when I call it, it throws this error at me:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of python are you using? If its `3.x` and above only then will `input` work.Dont assign the last line to a variable( i.e. the second `input` statement. If you still want to, use a different variable

Comment: It is, it's Python 3.3.2, so I can't define multiple user inputs? Ok, I'll try that with the end of the program.

Comment: Always avoid using python `keywords` as a variable name. `input` is a keyword and that makes it a big no as a `variable` name choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this line here:?

> ```
> input = ...
> ```

See a few lines above where you call the `input()` function? You've confused the compiler. Use a different name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be your last line, where you are assigning a value to the variable 'input'. See this previous SO question: [Local Variable Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873285/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-input-referenced-before-assignment)