# Why am I not able to catch both NameError and UnboundLocalError in the same except block in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling

A little background-- I have a Python program that makes plots from CSV files. I'm trying to make it more flexible by allowing a user to input between 1 and 3 files. I import the csv data into pandas data frames that are then used to generate a number of different plots.

I'm sure there's a better way to do what I'm doing, but I came across something strange (to me, at least) in my initial attempt to figure out if a user had input less than the maximum number of files.

Here is how I import the data:

```
# Imports the data.  The first two rows must be skipped due to the file format
data1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, skiprows=1, header=True)
if filename2 != '':
    data2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, skiprows=1, header=True)
if filename3 != '':
    data3 = pd.read_csv(filename3, skiprows=1, header=True)
```

So `data2` and `data3` are only defined if a user has provided a file name from my GUI.  Later, I just wanted to use the existence of `data2` and `data3` to determine whether or not to plot the 2nd and 3rd data sets, respectively:

```
    try:
        axarr[1, 0].psd(data1[Ynew], NFFT=n_samples, Fs=fs, noverlap=n_overlap, window=mlab.window_hanning, label=baseFileName1)
    except KeyError:
        axarr[1, 0].psd(data1[Yold], NFFT=n_samples, Fs=fs, noverlap=n_overlap, window=mlab.window_hanning, label=baseFileName1)
    try:
        axarr[1, 0].psd(data2[Ynew], NFFT=n_samples, Fs=fs, noverlap=n_overlap, window=mlab.window_hanning, label=baseFileName2)
    except (UnboundLocalError, NameError):
        pass
    except KeyError:
        axarr[1, 0].psd(data2[Yold], NFFT=n_samples, Fs=fs, noverlap=n_overlap, window=mlab.window_hanning, label=baseFileName2)
    try:
        axarr[1, 0].psd(data3[Ynew], NFFT=n_samples, Fs=fs, noverlap=n_overlap, window=mlab.window_hanning, label=baseFileName3)
    except (UnboundLocalError, NameError):
        pass
    except KeyError:
        axarr[1, 0].psd(data3[Yold], NFFT=n_samples, Fs=fs, noverlap=n_overlap, window=mlab.window_hanning, label=baseFileName3)
```

And here's where it got weird. When I run the thing, it throws an UnboundLocalError telling me that 'NameError' is referenced before assignment. So that except block that's supposed to catch the UnboundLocalError isn't passing like I would expect. If I try to catch just the UnboundLocalError, a NameError is thrown. If I try to catch just a NameError, an UnboundLocalError is thrown.  Can somebody explain to me what's going on here?

EDIT- Here's the traceback:

[Error Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB4Xr.png)

Comment: Please include a complete stack trace.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: It would also be useful to try to boil this down to a self-contained example. For one thing, that makes it easier to focus on the actual problem. For another, it often reveals an underlying cause. I suspect it will this time, referencing `NameError` should not be throwing any exceptions.

Comment: @jwodder -- Python 2.7

Comment: @DYZ added the traceback screen capture.

Comment: According to the stack trace, the error is on line 342 of some file that is not included in the question. How can we reason about it?

Comment: @DYZ-- line 342 is included here, I just didn't know how to include the line numbers (sorry, first post). The error is occurring on the line with the first attempt to catch the (UnboundLocalError, NameError).

Comment: Can you search your file for "NameError = " to see if you are accidentally shadowing the builtin NameError with an assignment?  That's the error you will get if you assign a variable 'input = 42' AFTER a call to the builtin input() function (all inside your own function).  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873285/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-input-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: @robert_x44-- I just searched, and I'm definitely not doing that anywhere.  That's what has me so confused about this one.

Comment: can you post the entire four_psd_plots function that includes the above try/except blocks.

Comment: Most likely, you've accidentally written `except UnboundLocalError, NameError` somewhere, without parentheses, creating a local variable named `NameError`.

Comment: In this case, catching only `NameError` would have been enough, because `UnboundLocalError` is a subclass of `NameError` (at least in Python 3).

Answer (score -1):

I've revisited this multiple times and there seems to be bug report for this sort of problem floating around out there.  Regardless, Exceptions are relatively expensive operations.  You can use something like the following to circumvent your problem and cut down on cycles.

```
data1 = None
data2 = None
data3 = None
if filename1 != '':
    data1 = ...
if filename2 != '':
    data2 = ...
if filename3 != '':
    data3 = ...

if data1 is not None:
    if Ynew in data1:
        axarr[1,0].psd(data1[Ynew] ...
    elif Yold in data1:
        axarr[1,0].psd(data1[Yold] ...
if data2 is not None:
    if Ynew in data2:
        axarr[1,0].psd(data2[Ynew] ...
    elif Yold in data2:
        axarr[1,0].psd(data2[Yold] ...
if data3 is not None:
    if Ynew in data3:
        axarr[1,0].psd(data3[Ynew] ...
    elif Yold in data3:
        axarr[1,0].psd(data3[Yold] ...
```

Comment: catching the exception is probably less expensive than doing O(n) search over `dataN` all the time.